# At symbol is in the wrong place on an Apple keyboard on Windows 7

Tags: keyboard, windows

We have an Apple keyboard connected to Windows 7 on a Sony laptop.

The email at "@" symbol is located on the <kbd>2</kbd> key, however when the <kbd>alt</kbd> key and <kbd>2</kbd> key are pressed simultaneously we don't get the "@" symbol, we get a quotation mark.

What settings need to be changed to rectify this?

Comment: Your keyboard layout is en-UK and you need to change it to en-US.

Comment: What happens if you press **shift** and **2** simultanesouly?  That's what I have to do to get "@".

Answer (score -1):

Use <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>.   At is in in quote. See onscreen keyboard. The symbols are swapped.